# Can you help me find resources for developing a top-down 2D game in Java?

Tags: 2d, java

I just started reading about games, and I'm going to develop a game where a person is moving around on a 2D map. My preferred language is Java. Is that suitable to develop games?

I'm going to develop a desktop app and need some help to get started. Can someone please give me some good resources for newbies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I am a big fan of [jMonkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/).Its a shader based & geared toward high end games productions. [jGame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/) & [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/index.php) are very good for 2d games. [ligGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) might interest you. All of these are under very active development.

There is no problem in choosing 3d engines for making 2d games. Just ignore that extra D, unless you have some serious issues with that one.

So, I whole heartily suggest you to start with jMonkey Engine, cause its fun, easy to use, has a very active community and comes with an awesome [jMonkey Platform](http://jmonkeyengine.com/sdk/) which is build on top of Netbeans platform, where every update & features is just one click away. You might end up in using it with many other projects.

There are other libraries too, but they lack community/development activity.

- Genuts - last update 2004
- PulpCore - last update 2009
- GOLDEN T GAME ENGINE (GTGE) - last update 2010
- Basilisk Game Library - last update 2009

You can write your own engine if want to.Then you should use opengl wrapper library, either [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) or JOGL. Lwjgl is more widely used then JOGL.

Comment: thank you very much for this valuable comment, is there else i need to know? like mathematics, vectors?

Comment: Linear algebra is important to get started.

Comment: thank you very much,, this is very helpful.. thank you again :)

Answer (score 3):

iamcreasy gave you some great examples of some engines to use for making a game in Java. They will definitely be helpful in your development process.

I wanted to give you a link to a good set of tutorials for 2D games in Java, without any engines. It walks through how to create some of the classics (like Tetris) in Java. The author walks you through them, explains the code, and is in general, a very big help.

You can find the above-mention tutorials here: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/

Hope this was a help, and good luck.