# How to make simple-graphics game

Tags: java

I just played minecraft and its awesome. I wanted to make game for years. I'm just not very interested in visual part and very interested in programming and making smart stuff. Mostly i make c/python/php programs with no interface at all. Now i think i found what i was looking for.

So my question is: how can i make simple but smart games like minecraft ? Cross-platform games with java seems like such a great idea. What technology is it using ? OpenGL ? Any 3d engines ? Can you help me please find the way to make smart games with minimal interface ? I'm interested in all platforms.

It doesn't have to be 3d. 2d is cool also. There is just so many different physics engines,  proprietary engines. Please help find the way to make small, smart, free games. (java/iOS/android/linux/win32).

Java is priority.

Comment: How to make a game is a *huge* question.  How about you try out some Java game engines listed here first: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15782/can-you-help-me-find-resources-for-developing-a-top-down-2d-game-in-java

Comment: -1, Not only is it a huge question, but there's some fundamental research that needs to be done.  For one, you can't run Java apps on an iOS device.

Comment: Minecraft is by no means a "simple" game. There is a lot of hidden complexity. I think you may be underestimating things a bit.

Comment: To chime in with what Adam said, Voxel based video games are not exactly the simplest.. yes Minecraft has a very simple appearance, and the cube environment does give it some benefits for voxel rendering, but it is still not an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Unity3d](http://www.unity3d.com). It compiles to Mac, PC, Web, iOS, Android, Wii, XBox, and PS3. It doesn't use java at all, but it has a visual editor, three scripting languages (javascript, c#, and python), physics, particle systems, image effects, 3d sound, networking, and more.

Answer (score 1):

It won't port straight to iOS or Android, but otherwise LWJGL is a good 3D Java library. http://lwjgl.org/ Not sure if there are any engines or SDKs that will support all the stated target platforms out of the box. Here's a 2D engine based on LWJGL : http://slick.cokeandcode.com/. LibGDX, http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ is for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft runs on the lightweight java game library engine, so I would look into the interface and API of it. Minecraft is pretty straight-forward with the coding, and how would I know this? Minecraft Coder Pack of course!
Minecraft coder pack:
http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases
Lightweight Java Game Library: http://lwjgl.org/